# How to differentiate between a unit test and an integration test?

Tags: python, pytest

I got this feedback during pull-request review:

> seems to be very mixed unit and integration test

Imagine you have a django backend test. Both types of tests use the same tools (pytest, ORM, mocking, ...)

How to differentiate between both types of tests?

Answer (score 1):

I would say that if it tests just one function then it is a unit test, if it tests a chain of more than one functions that interact with each other then it is an integration test.

[This page explains it well.](https://www.fullstackpython.com/integration-testing.html)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Michael, unit tests are targeting the smallest possible case eg:

```
assert add(2, 4) == 6
```

An integration test contains more moving parts that may need to be stubbed/faked/mocked eg:

```
assert mult(10, add(2, 5)) == 70
```

You can say integration tests are checking how well **units are integrating with each other**.
For tests including even more 'moving' parts of the application system tests are made.

Here's a video explaining it well:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vqAaMVoKz1c&feature=youtu.be